# Get missing values (geom_point)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I plot a graph with `ggplot2`, and I keep getting this message

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I want to be able to know which are the guilty rows.

My data is http://pastebin.com/xq0ccdF3

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xq0ccdF3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like, `which(x %in% NA)` where `x` is your data passed to `ggplot2`.

For example,

```
x <- c(1,2,NA,4,4,NA)
which(x %in% NA)
```

returns `[1] 3 6`
and

```
which(x %in% 4)
```

returns `[1] 4 5`

Comment: But in my case there isn't a NA value

Comment: check again: 233      2005  43.2     NA

Comment: 278      2012  23.6     NA

Comment: Those are your two problem rows. The command I gave you will find them for you.

Comment: `is.na` is probably a better tool for this, since that's what it's designed for.

Comment: true, wasn't sure there were NAs until I looked at the data so I included something that could check for anything (e.g. blanks "").

Comment: `na.omit` and `complete.case` are also tools to deal with `NA`.